# Find selected value in a server side for a dropdown list that populated by client side

Tags: vb.net, drop-down-menu, webforms

I have a dropdown list with select2 inside a grid view template item which is inside an update panel also. I was able to populate it normaly from the back end on RowCreated event but when data grow it takes a while with each row to be populated specially when user add a new row.

Instead, I use AJAX to populate the dropdown list based on user input in the select2 search box which minimized data loading and it works perfectly.

My problem here is when a dropdown list populated in client side, on change, the selected value can't be accessed by server side.

This is my grid view code.

```
     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:GridView ID="grd1" runat="server" CssClass="table" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                        <Columns>                        
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Account" ItemStyle-Width="300px">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="comAccounts" runat="server" CssClass="form-control d-inline-block Accounts " DataValueField="ID" DataTextField="FullName" AppendDataBoundItems="True" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="comAccounts_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="-" Value="0" />
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CostCenter" ItemStyle-Width="150px">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="comCostCenters" runat="server" CssClass="form-control select2 d-inline-block" DataValueField="ID" DataTextField="Name" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="-" Value="0" />
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description" ItemStyle-Width="350px">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" CssClass="form-control d-inline-block Journal" dir="rtl" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And this is the AJAX that I use to populate the drop down list.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.Accounts').select2({
                ajax: {
                    url: '../cls/AutoComplete.asmx/Accounts',
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    delay: 500,
                    data: function (params) {

                        var search = '';

                        if (params.term !== undefined) {
                            search = params.term;
                        }

                        return "{'AccountName': '" + search + "','Level': '2'}";
                    },
                    processResults: function (data) {
                        var items = JSON.parse(data.d).items

                        if (items == null) {
                            return null;
                        }

                        return {
                            results: items
                        };
                    }
                },
                allowClear: true,
                minimumInputLength: 3
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Is there any solution, or any other suggested approach to achieve the same goal.

Comment: I see you have a `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event handler. Have you tried the `OnTextChanged` event instead? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist?view=netframework-4.8.1#declarative-syntax)